# Azure PHP SDK throws Fatal Exception with Socket error

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage-queues

My PHP script reads from my DB and sends messages to the queue so that worker roles (well other LAMP machines) can pull them and work in parallel.

However, often times my script ends with a Fatal Error with the following message in my error_log on my apache server. This error is on the sending side.

```
PHP Notice:  fwrite(): send of 414 bytes failed with errno=32 
Broken pipe in /home/azureuser/pear/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/SocketWrapper.php on line 202

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught HTTP_Request2_MessageException: 
Error writing request in /home/azureuser/pear/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php 
on line 130

Exception trace

HTTP_Request2_SocketWrapper->write('POST /proxy/mess&hellip;')
/home/azureuser/pear/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/Adapter/Socket.php:130

HTTP_Request2_Adapter_Socket->sendRequest(Object(HTTP_Request2))
/home/azureuser/pear/share/pear/HTTP/Request2.php:93 

in /home/azureuser/pear/share/pear/HTTP/Request2/SocketWrapper.php on line 206
```

It seems to me the socket throws an exception for some reason that is not handled and thus crashes the script. If you agree, do you suggest it is a good idea to fix the SDK?

Answer (score 1):

Looked into this really quickly for a first pass, but it seems:

```
fwrite(): send of 414 bytes failed with errno=32
```

Refers to a dropped socket, which could happen for a few reasons:

- The site goes into a Cold state (turn on always on)
- The socket is staying open extremely long and terminated by the LB
- Something unexpected happened and the socket crashes (think exception writing to the Queue)

Have you been able to look at the FREB logs or run the PHP Process Report in the Support Portal (https://[site-name].scm.azurewebsites.net/Support) to diagnose the why the socket is being dropped?

Comment: Thanks Cory. I will investigate into that and see if that fixes it. It is a virtual machine running Linux so I'll double check my logs to see if I missed anything. Will get back if I need further help.

Comment: Oops... Spent the day doing App Service Questions, so was in that answer mode. Cold State doesn't apply, but the other two still do.

Comment: It's a good thing you are in answer mode :) This is a common problem across a few apps that we have built though. I have started to feel it's me because I do not see others reporting this error much. I am messing with socket time out and some code cleaning. Hopefully that should be it.

Comment: @dinwal Did you manage to get this worked out? I'd love to hear your feedback

Comment: I am afraid not. I am able to catch the exception now but the error of socket dropping has not solved yet. I tried setting various values for default socket timeout but nothing helped. This is actually an error across many of my websites running on Azure Linux virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the endpoint timeout value to which your php socket is connecting to. The default timeout is 4 mins for a VM endpoint. You can change this to a higher value. Here is the article on how to do that. https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/

Check this section: "Set Idle Timeout when creating an Azure endpoint on a Virtual Machine" in above link.